# js append with drop down list in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am new in cakephp and 
i want to create a dynamic row while click on the Go button.
i use the append() of js 
its also work but when i put a code for dropdown list in append(),and the list contain data from the database so when i use this dropdown the append() can't work

my controller:

```
class RoomDetailsController extends AppController {

    var $name = "RoomDetails";

    public $helpers = array('Js');
    public $components  = array('RequestHandler');
}
```

my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() 
{

    $("#add").click(function()
    {
        var room = $('#total_room').val();
        alert("This is total no of room ");
        alert(room);
        for(var i=1; i<=room; i++)
        {
            $('#datatable').append
            (
                '<table border="0"> <tr> <td>Room No</td> <td>:</td>
                 <td  colspan="2">  <?php echo $roomno; ?>  </td> 
                 <td>Room Categories</td> <td>:</td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $roomcat;  ?> 
                 </td> <td>Room Capacities</td> <td>:</td> 
                 <td> <?php echo $roomcap;  ?> </td> 
                 </tr></table>'

            );

            if(i == room)
            {
                $("#submit").append(
                '<?php echo $this->Form->end(_("Submit")); ?>');
            }
        }

    });
});

</script>
```

but it cant work when i will put dropdown in appen() ,
so plz help to do this